# adding multiple search queries to search script?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out a way of allowing users to search by multiple queries, at the moment the search script i have only allows one true like for like matching word with which is like that in the database.

So if i type women i get all women users, but what i want to be able to do is allow users to type brown haired women.

being that 'haired' is not a query and is not stored in the database but would still allow for the search to bring up query = 'brown' and query = 'women'.

I tried simply replacing OR like '%".query."%' with AND but this means that if the user searches for just women nothing will show because its asking to include all the queries then.

Can anyone please show me how i can do this I'm really struggling?

Thanks.

```
<?php
//PHP CODE STARTS HERE

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="";
$db_tb_atr_name="display_name";

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);


$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM ptb_stats
                        WHERE display_name like '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR sex LIKE '%".$query."%' OR nationality LIKE '%".$query."%' OR ethnicity LIKE '%".$query."%' OR age LIKE '%".$query."%' OR local_station LIKE '%".$query."%' OR height LIKE '%".$query."%' OR weight LIKE '%".$query."%' OR status LIKE '%".$query."%' OR build LIKE '%".$query."%' LIMIT 5");
echo "<div class=\"search-results\">";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))

{

    echo "<div class=\"text\"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$data_fetch['user_id']}\" class=\"search\">";
    echo "<div class=\"spacing\"><img width=35px height= 30px src=\"data/photos/{$data_fetch['user_id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgridsearch\"/> "; 
     echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
    echo "</a></div></div>";

}
echo "<div class=\"morebutton-search\"><a href=\"search_results.php?query=$query\">+ view more results</a></div>";



mysql_close();
}

?>
```

Comment: split the query-string to sub words usually $words = explode(" ", $string);  will do the job, then $words is an array now you can built your query again...

Answer (score 0):

Use full text search

`mysql_query("SELECT *,MATCH(display_name, location, sex, nationality, ethnicity, age, local_station, height, weight, status, build) AGAINST ('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM ptb_stats WHERE MATCH(display_name, location, sex, nationality, ethnicity, age, local_station, height, weight, status, build) AGAINST('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 5");`

Here

```
('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
```

means you get the results in order of relevance, but if you wish to order it in any other mysql ways like random() you can use:

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ptb_stats WHERE MATCH(display_name, location, sex, nationality, ethnicity, age, local_station, height, weight, status, build) AGAINST('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by random() DESC LIMIT 5");`

Comment: sorry where am i placing the full text search? where the SELECT * query already is? whats the ('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance and where does that go?

Comment: oh wait i just edited the answer that had errors. Just copy the first code and replace it instead of mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM ptb_stats
                        WHERE display_name like .......LIMIT 5");

Comment: There are different modes of searching, this one is boolean mode. You can check out the whole reference of mysql here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html